# Upgrading MVC 4 RC to MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

As you know, [ASP.NET MVC 4 was finally released a couple of weeks ago.](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes) I have been working with MVC 4 RC for a couple months now when the application is complete. I wonder if I have to upgrade it to its release version. Better questions would be:

1. How much do I have to change in web api and server code by upgrading?
2. How can I upgrade to release version? As far as I can see, there are several way to do it, single standalone installer, web installer, and nuget. Is that right? What's the best way to upgrade from RC? I tried web installer but I can find only ASP.NET MVC 4 Tools Update with Language Packs.

Any advice or tip would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mainly use the Web APi, but I found using nuget to update the dependencies individually trouble free.

Changes: there is a signature change for custom formatters for the WriteToStreamAsync method

```
WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream stream, HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders, TransportContext transportContext)
```

to:

```
WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
```

Also filters are added to the HttpFilterCollection rather than the GlobablFilterCollection.

I think thats all i encountered.

A list of the packages i updated:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0-beta3" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

You can use the package id's above when searching for them in nuget

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That sounds great. But could you tell us more detail about `using nuget to update the dependencies individually`? A couple of examples would be great. Thanks again.

Comment: you can use the nuget gui by right clicking on your solution "manage nuget packages for solution" from there you can uninstall ASP.NET MVC, Webapi etc. And then search for the newest packages and install them, i think the new version numbers are 4.0.20710

Comment: @david Updated with the packages